# Admobs : AdWork Security Exception in Kitkat v4.4.2 while it works perfeclty in Jelly Beans as well as v4.4.2 Emulator

Tags: android

Suddenly My app which used Google Admobs started crashing and the exception shown was SecurityException in Adworker Thread. I could easily concluded that this is problem with Google Admobs. I saw many post on StackOverFlow but no clear cut solution except telling that this is the Bug.

Any Solution exists for it?

Neeraj Swarnkar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer by myself. This is a bug in Kitkat, which can be resolved in upcoming releases. If you are facing this problem, just add following permission in your android manifest file:

com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES